# Way to make row count be 0 if no date match and second,third,etc while loop row counts

Tags: mysql

```
<?php 

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table")) {
    if($count = $result->num_rows) {
        echo '<p class="lead">Number of callbacks for today is: ', $count, '</p>';

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          if ( $row['field'] == date("Y-m-d") ) {
             echo $row['otherfield'], '<br>';
          }else{
             echo "Nothing", '' , '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have a simple field date verses server date test used in conjunction with a while loop to bring up any callbacks each day if they are due.  My issue is that the row will show a nothing for every row so I'll have twenty(example) rows of the text 'nothing' display.  I know I could simply place everything in a function and then use the if/else statement outside of the function to display callbacks or not display callbacks....but is there a way to reset the loop counter to zero if the first if/else test fails?  I tried placing the `$count = 0;` in the second else clause but this did not work.

Comment: so what outcome you expecting? only one time display of `nothing` or  `$row['otherfield']`?

Comment: Well, sorry, I guess I should further clarify... the page output would be "You have eg:8 callbacks today.  But if there were no matching dates in the array then I would simply like the text to say 'You have 0 callbacks today.  I realize this else clause with the echo statement will spit out 'nothing' on each none-match.  It would be preferable if I could scrap the 'Nothing' bit and just get a '0' where the eight might be on another day..savvy?

Comment: Maaybe an if/else clause above the while loop testing the date match, then only using the while clause if there is a match could do the trick?  Yes Im expecting only one display of 'Nothing